# Get Multiple Select value After Button Event

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I need  to find using Vue,how to get the selected value of two select, and some input values after pressing a button.

How can achieve this and can u provide me a simple example?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you get a value of an element by: `document.getElementById("id").value`. You jsut use the line multiple times to load differend select or input id's.

Comment: @tacoshy nope mate, that's not how it works in Vue.. he just needed to make a little search https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get values from inputs & selects in vue, you must bind using v-model.
The button event is handled by using `@click` attribute.

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Console log values:</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="inputValue">
  <select name="firstSelect" v-model="firstSelectedValue">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="firstSelect" v-model="secondSelectedValue">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  
  <button @click="getData">Get Data</button>
</div>
```

In the JS part, you must define the data to bind to & the button method:

Here's a link to the doc to event handling in vue: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    firstSelectedValue: null,
    secondSelectedValue: null,
    inputValue: '',
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function(){
        console.log("Input value: "+ this.inputValue);
        console.log("First selected value: " + this.firstSelectedValue);
      console.log("Second selected value: " +this.secondSelectedValue);
      }
  }
})
```

Here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2wux39sp/36/ that will console log the requested data.